# How to convert mysqli code to PDO stmt?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, pdo

```
 if($_REQUEST['action'] == 'addToCart' && !empty($_REQUEST['id'])){
        $productID = $_REQUEST['id'];
        // get product details
        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ".$productID);
        $row = $query->fetch_assoc();
        $itemData = array(
            'id' => $row['id'],
            'name' => $row['name'],
            'price' => $row['price'],
            'qty' => 1
        );

        $insertItem = $cart->insert($itemData);
        $redirectLoc = $insertItem?'viewCart.php':'index.php';
        header("Location: ".$redirectLoc);
    }
```

I'm trying to convert this code to PDO stmt. Please help me with this, I'm new here.

Comment: `$db` is a `pdo` connection or `mysqli`? What have you done so far? `prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ?"`.. `execute(array($productID))`

Comment: You might want to show us your database class so we can see what it's doing

Answer (score 0):

You need to develop and pdo connection with whichever database you have. Check the connection check and connect with it.

Make sure that you have install PDO library, check it your php info.

```
   try
    {                   
        $conn =new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$this->hostName;Database=$this->dbName", "$this->userName", "$this->password");
        $productID = $_REQUEST['id'];   
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE id=?"; 
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $productID);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $this->result = $stmt->execute();

                    if (!$this->result) 
                    {
                        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                        {
                             $itemData = array(
                            'id' => $row['id'],
                            'name' => $row['name'],
                            'price' => $row['price'],
                            'qty' => 1
                            );
                        }
                    }
    $insertItem = $cart->insert($itemData);
    $redirectLoc = $insertItem?'viewCart.php':'index.php';
    header("Location: ".$redirectLoc);                          
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
                    exit();
    }
```